# AMD Ryzen can't start Android Emulator: x86 Emulation Hardware Acceleration problem

Tags: android-studio

I just installed Android Studio 3.3.2 on Windows 10 for the second time.
The first time i installed it i had no problems, i followed the steps to emulate an Android device by enabling SVM mode in bios and i have turned on Hyper-V feature in Windows (services included). Everything worked fine and i used that configuration for a month.
The processor i use is an AMD Ryzen 3 1300x.

Recently i installed Windows 10 on SSD as the main operating system and i downloaded Android Studio and all. Now i repeated all the steps i did the first time but it doesn't work and gives me "Emulator: emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!".

I tried to create 3 different devices with 3 different API Level: 28, 27 and 26. None of which worked.
The Android Studio version i installed is up to date and i downloaded it two times to be sure nothing was wrong with the files.

Comment: Looks like other people have run into this issue before https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/296/how-to-solve-android-avd-error-in-windows-x86-emulation-currently-requires-hardware-acceleration

Comment: @KevinVandy That solution works only for Intel processors